# PayPal REST API - how to get information (webhooks?) on manual money transfers

Tags: rest, paypal

I have a working integration with PayPal Rest API but I can't figure out how to get information about manual transfers (a user logs into PayPal and sends money to my PayPal E-mail).

It seems this does not trigger the usual `Payment.Capture.Completed` webhooks, makes sense as I do not actively capture them but I can't find any other webhook event for this case.
In sandbox I activated the webhook wildcard "all events" but a manual transfer did not trigger anything.
Google did not help me either, I guess I am missing the right keywords.

Did I miss something? What is the desired way to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of [your list of live applications](https://developer.paypal.com/dashboard/applications/live), it is possible NVP/SOAP Webhooks will send notifications for such payments. This **cannot** be tested in sandbox mode.

Otherwise, you will need to use the old (nearly deprecated) IPN service.